# Implement Arrow Up key, and Tab auto complete in custom shell in C

Tags: c, linux, terminal, readline

I'm making my own shell and I'm trying to implement the use that when the key arrow up is pressed, it returns the last thing I typed, or tab auto-complete, like the Linux terminal, the thing is that when I press the key up, I see in screen: "^[[A", or using tab I only got a tabulation, how can I implement this in my code? I tried using libraries like <ncurses.h>, <readline/readline.h>, <readline/history.h>, and in makefile adding -lreadline -lncurses at the end of the file like this:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic

myshell: main.o myShell.o   
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o myshell main.o myShell.o -lreadline -lncurses

main.o: main.c  
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -o main.o

myShell.o: myShell.c    
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c myShell.c -o myShell.o

clear:
    rm -f myshell *.o *.out
```

But nothing happens, do I need to include something? Just in case, I have a function where I read what I type in the terminal like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ /* shell loop */

    char command[COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *tokens[TOKEN_BUFFER_SIZE];

    int token_Size = 0;
    int blk = 0;
    int aux = 0;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        inputOption(&argv[1][0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    signal(SIGINT, handlerC);
    signal(SIGTSTP, handlerZ);
    signal(SIGQUIT, handlerBS);

    //kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);

    while (1)
    {

        using_history();
        do
        {
            customPrompt();
            fgets(command, COMMAND_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        } while (strlen(command) < 2);

        token_Size = 0;

        token_Size = parse(command, tokens, token_Size);
...
}
```

This is something that I use, I guess that is in this method below what I should change in order to make it work.

```
int parse(char *input, char *args[], int size)

    {
    
        int i = 0;
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
        args[i] = strtok(input, " ");
        add_history(args[i]);
        while ((args[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ")))
        {
            size++;
        }
    
        return size;
    }
```

EDIT: Just in case, I will add the libraries I have included in this program...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
```

Could anyone please give me a hand?

Comment: I assume you have to switch terminal to a special mode which will pass special combinations to your program. Not sure how to do that, `ncurses` docs should be able to clarify, probably.

Comment: I would be looking at GNU Readline, myself.  But do understand that just including its header(s) and linking the library to your program will be of no use if you don't actually call any of its functions.  In particular, you would want to obtain command input via its [`readline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline) function.  You might also need to configure it for your needs, whether programmatically, by config file, or both.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought that when using add_history(), I was managing that, that it was that function that did the work of getting the up arrow up, not also with readline() :/

Comment: @IvoFerrari, if you want the shell to be immediately responsive to user keystrokes then naturally, that has to be handled by whatever function is actually reading the keystrokes.  `fgets()` does not do that -- all you get that way is whatever the terminal device does by default.  There may be more to do than just engage `readline()` instead of `fgets()`, but changing out `fgets()` for something else is definitely one thing you'll need to do.